# htaccess with Laravel on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I need your help. I have deployed Laravel app on shared hosting, and I have added htaccess file in order to redirect all traffic to public dir. Structure of directories is following:

```
public_html
|
-------my_website
|
-------.htaccess
```

I know, I should not do this and the right way is to put Laravel's public dir content in public_html and the rest of Laravel app should be outside of it, but in this case I am not in position to do it because of some reasons (not code related). And now I have a problem because anyone can access sensitive parts of website by hitting direct url, for example:

http://mywebsite.com/my_website/database/database.sqlite

I do not have extensive knowledge about htaccess, and have spent a lot of time searching how to protect sensitive files, but I was not able to accomplish this. My htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mywebsite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mywebsite/public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mywebsite/public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an example, because you show a link to an sqlite file, consider this:

```
RewriteRule ^mywebsite/database - [F,L]
```

This would keep HTTP requests to that sqlite file from being permitted. You can also add other directories to that, so if you also want to protect directory foo, then:

```
RewriteRule ^mywebsite/(database|foo) - [F,L]
```

This is a really common technique for protecting directories of PHP applications running on Apache

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! One more question, is there a way I can protect all folders/files except public? For example, something like this: RewriteRule ^mywebsite/(!public) - [F,L]

Comment: Not likely, because it is looking at the URL when it is coming in. It is just regex though, so you might be able to come up with something.

Comment: Managed to solve it with `RewriteRule ^mywebsite/((?!public).)* - [F,L]` Thank you, you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

works with me on a shared host and start the project from the public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<Files .env>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This repo on github](https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-deploy-on-shared-hosting), is a good tutorial on how to deploy laravel on a shared host

Comment: This does not help me, it moves all project files outside of public_html. But I appreciate the effort!